# How to distinguish between "0" and null?

Tags: php, null, comparison

I have a database with some football scores (goal differences).

**p12_score1** contains 3, -2, 0 and NULL

All I want to do is to print all score differences (including 0) and ignore the row that has no value (NULL in mysql). However is_null also considers the value 0 a null and won't print it.

```
IF(!$p12_score1==NULL){
$equal[] = $p12_score1;
}
else {
echo "null";
}
print_r ($equal);
```

Comment: use `if (!$p12_score1 === null)` see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_null`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) does *not* consider the value `0` equal to `null`.

Your code uses `==` for the comparison, which does not make this distinction. Use the [identical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) `===` or `is_null` instead:

```
// One way to do it:
if(!$p12_score1 !== NULL)

// Another:
if(!is_null($p12_score1))
```

Answer (score 1):

> However is_null also considers the value 0 a null and won't print it.

No. http://codepad.org/mjiGfhTB

However, you use the comparisong operator

```
$p12_score1==NULL
```

and in this case: In loosely typed languaged `null` is equal to `0` (and some others ;)). However, PHP supports the identity-comparisong

```
$p12_score1===NULL
```

A sidenote: `!$a == $b` is slightly ugly. Use the *real* "not equal" `!=`, or `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF(!empty($p12_score1)){
$equal[] = $p12_score1;
}
else {
echo "null";
}
print_r ($equal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if($p12_score1 !== null) {
    $equal[] = $p12_score1;
} else {
echo "null";
}
print_r ($equal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in PHP instead of sql you have to change your code to this:

```
IF (!$p12_score1 === NULL)
```

This way you check that `$p12_score1` is **exactly** null.

Answer (score 0):

The function `is_null` should work. Another option is `is_int`. I tried both and both work correctly.